How to Replace a MethodCall With a Lambda in Visit()
I have code that will replace an annotated property in a LINQ query with a predefined lambda.  Here's an example of such a property, followed by the Visitor code that does the replacement:
public class example
{
    private int[] numbers { get; set; }
    
    [Expression(nameof(MaxExpression))]
    public int Max => MaxCompiled(this);
    public static Func<example, int> MaxCompiled = MaxExpression.Compile();
    public static Expression<Func<example, int>> MaxExpression = x => x.numbers.Max();

Visitor:
class SpecificationsProcessor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        logger.Error($" member:{node.Member.Name} ");
        if (node.Expression != null && node.Member is PropertyInfo property)
        {
            var info = property.GetCustomAttribute<ExpressionAttribute>();
            if (info != null)
            {
                var type = property.DeclaringType;
                var specificationMemberInfo = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                    .Single(x => x.Name == info.Name);
                var specification = (LambdaExpression)specificationMemberInfo.GetValue(null);
                var expression = specification.Body.ReplaceParameter(
                    specification.Parameters.Single(), Visit(node.Expression));
                return Visit(expression);
            }
        }

        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }

That works perfectly for all kinds of properties.  Now I want to do the same for methods with arguments, like this:
[Expression(nameof(NthExpression))]
public int? Nth(int n) => NthCompiled(this, n);
public static Expression<Func<PlantTb, int, int?>> NthExpression = (x, n) =>
            n < x.numbers.Length ? x.numbers[n] : null;
public static Func<PlantTb, int, int?> NthCompiled = NthExpression.Compile();

I don't have a deep understanding of this stuff, so I tried doing basically the same thing for this as for properties, like so:
protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
{
    logger.Error($" call:{node.Method.Name} ");
    if (node.Method is MethodInfo method)
    {
        var info = method.GetCustomAttribute<ExpressionAttribute>();
        if (info != null)
        {
            var type = method.DeclaringType;
            var specificationMemberInfo = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                .Single(x => x.Name == info.Name);
            var specification = (LambdaExpression)specificationMemberInfo.GetValue(null);
            var expression = specification.Body.ReplaceParameter(
                specification.Parameters[0], Visit(node.Arguments[0]))
                .ReplaceParameter(specification.Parameters[1], Visit(node.Arguments[1]));
            return Visit(expression);
        }
    }
    return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
}

... but of course that didn't work.  I got
System.ArgumentException: Property 'Int32[] numbers' is not defined for type 'System.Int32'
    at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(Expression expression, PropertyInfo property)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitConditional(ConditionalExpression node)
   at Util.ExpressionExtensions.ReplaceParameter(Expression source, ParameterExpression from, Expression to) 

I'd very much appreciate code that correctly merges the parameters with the lambda to make the whole thing work.
TIA

You are duplicating functionality of LINQKit, NeinLinq, etc. So they have this code. Check this implementation also.
